# How to know how many Event have beed added in UWP?

Tags: uwp

For example I have a ToggleSwitch named tiggerBtnSwitch, and I added Event as below.

```
tiggerBtnSwitch.Toggled += TiggerBtnSwitch_Toggled;
```

Due to some reason, the above line is executed for more than one time. And I want to know, how many `Event` (`RoutedEventHandler`) have already beed added. So that I could subtract the redundant Events like below.

```
tiggerBtnSwitch.Toggled -= TiggerBtnSwitch_Toggled;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no clear API to know how many subscribers an event has. But here is a way we can avoid duplicate subscriptions.

**Remove subscription before adding event subscription.**

```
// before add
tiggerBtnSwitch.Toggled -= TiggerBtnSwitch_Toggled;
// then add
tiggerBtnSwitch.Toggled += TiggerBtnSwitch_Toggled;
```

I looked at some of the removal of event subscriptions in WPF, but they don't apply to UWP. So a better way is to add event listeners only once.